# UICollectionView - pass array date via segue for selected indexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used a collectionview to present some data - all is fine but I'm struggling with passing the data to a child view by a segue - basically I need to pass the array data for the index path clicked - this is what I have at the mo -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sightSeg"]) {
    NSArray *thisarr = [_sightsColView indexPathsForSelectedItems];


    SightViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];

    destController.viewTit = thisarr.siteTitle;


    }
}
```

I currently get an error stating 'property not found on type nsarray'.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a property "siteTitle" of an object of type NSArray that is not natively provided by iOS, since it is your custom property not a native NSArray property.
Supposing that your array contains a dictionary for each element into the array, you could do something like this:

```
// Implement the collection view delegate method
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
            didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedItemIndex = indexPath.row; // define NSInteger selectedItemIndex property in your interface
}



// then in your prepareForSegue
...
..
.

NSDictionary* selectedItem = (NSDictionary*)[yourDatasource objectAtIndex:self.selectedItemIndex ];

SightViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];
destController.viewTit = [selectedItem objectForKey:@"siteTitle"];

// Otherwise if it is a simple nsarray contains strings only 
// ( so each element in the   array is directly the title of a different view ) you could simply:

NSString* selectedTitle = (NSString*)[yourDatasource objectAtIndex:self.selectedItemIndex ];

SightViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];
destController.viewTit = selectedTitle ;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess you data source object for the selected collection cell implements a `siteTitle` property? However, `thisarr` contains objects of the class `NSIndexPath`, i.e. just a "pointer" where to find the object for the selected cell you are interested in. Use the index path(s) to get the approriate object(s) from your actual data source.

Answer (score 0):

Collection views support multiple selection. For that reason, the indexPathsForSelectedItems method returns an array of NSIndexPath objects, one for each selected item.

As Luca Iaco suggests in his post, you can set up your code to respond do the didSelectRowAtIndexPath message, and record the row of the item the user selected.

Based on what you're trying to do, you likely only want single selection. You should set the allowsMultipleSelection flag to false on your collection view in that case.

You can ask the collection view for the current selection using indexPathsForSelectedItems, then fetch the first item in the array:

```
NSArray *selectedItems = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems;
NSIndexPath *selectedItem = selectedItems[0];
int selectedIndex = selectedItem.row;

MyClass *item = (MyClass *) thisarr[selectedIndex];
NSString title = item.siteTitle;
```

Where you would replace "MyClass" above with the class of your object that is in the thisArr array and has a "siteTitle" property.